# Export data from database to xlsx file (Excel) using spring

Tags: excel, database, spring-boot, export

I need to export data from database to excel document using spring.
But when I download from controller document I get message that is currupted file or wrong extension.

```
private static final String EXCEL_FILE_NAME = "UserExcelExport.xlsx";
@GetMapping("/download")
  public void download(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    List<User> users = userService.getUsers();

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("All Users List");
    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Username");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("First name");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Last name");
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue("E-mail");
    int rowNum = 1;
    for (User user : users) {
      Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue(user.getUsername());
      row.createCell(1).setCellValue(user.getFirstName());
      row.createCell(2).setCellValue(user.getLastName());
      row.createCell(3).setCellValue(user.getEMail());
    }

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + EXCEL_FILE_NAME);

    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is missing the content-type:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Also use XSSFWorkbook to generate an `.xlsx` file:

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

Edit~~~~

Here is a full example that works, I use SpringBoot 2.2.2 and POI 3.15.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/main/export")
public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // user list  
    List<UserDto> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new UserDto(1L, "user1"));
    users.add(new UserDto(2L, "user2"));

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("All Users List");
    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Username");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("First name");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Last name");
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue("E-mail");

    int rowNum = 1;

    for (UserDto user : users) {
        Row aRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        aRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(user.getId());
        aRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(user.getName());
    }

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());

}
```

Comment: I tried using you suggestion. But a corrupted file is generated.

Comment: Edited the answer, you need to use a different approach for XLSX files

Comment: New comment, i have same issue

Comment: Added a full example which I was able to run, note I use Office for 365, not sure if your version is different

Answer (score 0):

I have same problm.
I tried using you suggestion.

```
@GetMapping("/download")
```

public void download(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

```
List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("All Users List");
Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Username");
header.createCell(1).setCellValue("First name");
header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Last name");
header.createCell(3).setCellValue("E-mail");

int rowNum = 1;

for (User user : users) {
  Row aRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
  aRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(user.getUsername());
  aRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(user.getFirstName());
  aRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(user.getLastName());
  aRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(user.getEMail());
}


response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

}

But when I download from controller document i get this:
[image]